# Sqlalchemy from sql using subqueries

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have folowing sql code:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.sample_id
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING NOW() > (SELECT end FROM table2 WHERE start = 
  max(t2.start)) + (t1.time::text||' minute')::interval
```

I need to rewrite this code in sqlalchemy like this:

```
Table1.query
   .join(Table2, Table1.id == Table2.sample_id)
   .group_by(Table1.id)
   .having(
      datetime.datetime.now() > ((Table2.query.filter_by(
         start= 
         (database.session.query(func.max(Table2.start)))
      )).first().end + 
         datetime.timedelta(minutes=Table1.query.filter_by(
            id=Table1.id
         ).first().frequency))).all()
```

This SQL query returns one line of data from the database, but my query in sqlalchemy returns empty dict. Can someone help me with my recreation of my SQL query?

Comment: Print the query without the `.all()` on the end. Does it read the same as your target query?

Comment: Also enable logging and observe if you're issuing a single query, or many.

Comment: When I print query without all() it doesnt show sql in HAVING part (there is only true or false), so I dont know if it is the same or not.